# Divert A Page To A New URL If Incorrect URL Parameter is manually Added - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, security, http-headers

I have a delete page that shows a user record from a MySQL database.

The delete functionality is done with a PHP prepared statement, and after this is executed the user is directed back to index.php (which shows a table of all the users)

Above the $_POST request that handles the deleting of the record in the code below, I have an if statement that checks for the 'id' url parameter, and if it isn't present it sends you back to index.php. I've set it up like this so if somebody changes the `id=45` url parameter to `delete=45` it sends them away from the page for security reasons.

Is there any way of having it so if a user types in a different url parameter value (that doesn't exist in the database) such as `id=49` it sends the user to an error page / different page using the `header()` method with a location string added?

I've tried `header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);` which I thought would effectively regenerate the page to what it was before the url parameter was changed, but I get the error message `Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** There is a link to the screenshot of the delete.php page below the code.

Anna

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

        $the_id = $_GET['id'];


    } else {

        // BELOW IS THE ORIGINAL RE-ROUTING TO INDEX.PHP AND THE OTHER IDEA I HAD
        // header("Location: index.php");
        // header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);

        exit;

    }

?>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $stmt = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE ID = ? ");

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $the_id);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();
        
        $connection->close();
        
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;

    } 
?>
```

How the table in the screenshot below is created.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>firstname</th>
            <th>email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = $the_id";
        $select_posts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_posts) ) {

            $user_id = htmlspecialchars($row['ID']);
            $firstname = htmlspecialchars($row['firstname']);
            $email = htmlspecialchars($row['email']);

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$user_id</td>";
            echo "<td>$firstname</td>";
            echo "<td>$email</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Screenshot of delete page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D05ru.png)

Comment: Never trust "HTTP_REFERER" and don't use it outside of firewall and logging cases.

Comment: _“so if the url parameter isn't `id=` it just stays on the same page and nothing changes? ”_ - stay on _what_ “same page”, exactly? If I tried to navigate to `yourscriptname.php?foo=bar` in my browser, then what exactly do you want to happen now?

Comment: Hi @CBroe - I would like it so if the user types in an id value that is different to what is shown on the page it either redirects to a different page or loads the page again with the original value (although a simple re-direct would be fine). I've added an image of the delete.php page so you can see how the ID value is presented in the document and edited the question so it is (hopefully) a bit clearer in terms of what I am trying to do. I appreciate being new to php i may be approaching this problem incorrectly.

Comment: Why would it _matter_, whether I arrive on `delete.php?id=95` by clicking a link, or whether I might have typed that link manually? Do you think this was related to security somehow - who is allowed to delete what? Then you’d really be approaching this from a completely wrong angle - that kind of check should happen the moment you perform the actual deletion, not be tied to any pages that display forms that trigger it.

Comment: @CBroe because when they enter the number manually in the url it deletes the table from the screen and just look weird. When I try this on proper websites and you do that either nothing happens or you get sent back to a main/homepage

Comment: _“because when they enter the number manually in the url it deletes the table from the screen and just look weird”_ - because its an ID that does not actually exist in your system, you mean? Well then write your script so that it outputs something else then, when it does not find any data for the ID in the database …

Comment: @CBroe Also I should mention I only want this to happen if the ID isn't a valid record in the database. Yes, if they re-type an id manually that exists this will just bring up that record which is fine.

Comment: @CBroe - in terms of your last comment, that's what my question is asking. I can't work out how to do this. I wouldn't expect someone to write the full code - even if it's just pseudo code that would be really useful.

Comment: You have not shown us any code for the part that creates this table in the first place … But surely, there will be a database query, and then a loop to build the table(?) So go and check how many rows your database query returned - _if_ that was more than zero, you do your loop that creates the table, and in the _else_ branch … do something different.

Comment: @CBroe - I've added the table code

Comment: Okay, but my last previous comment should contain enough info for you to give it a try yourself already.

Comment: What is behind the "Yes Delete" button, does it send the form-data to the same file (delete.php) with the same parameters (id=95). Like a confirmation link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly...you're trying to divert the user if the $get[] does not match anything in the table....you could use mysqli_num_rows...
The code below will divert the user or you could print some other result if no row matches the id..

```
<?php 

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = $the_id";
        $select_posts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($select_posts);

        if($num_rows==0) {
                echo "something else"; OR header("Location: errorpage.php");
                         }
            else {

       //your while() code here 
                 }
    ?>
```

Comment: Ah this works ! thank you - i didn't realise there was a `mysqli_num_rows()` method. This was the why I couldn't get any variant of using `$select_posts` to work in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

**First solving the issue with the redirect:**

If the browser doesn't provide a "Referer" header, your redirection will fail with an "Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER" error.

What you could do instead is:

1. Check if the header is available (using `isset()`);
2. Use it in case it exists;
3. Use a default error link in the other case.

If you are using PHP a modern version of PHP, which I hope you are, you can use the `??` operator:

```php
<?php 

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $the_id = $_GET['id'];
    } else {
        // redirect to google if $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is not set
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ?? 'http://google.com');
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Note: I'd personally prefer to send user to an error url and not "back", but is up to you.

**Second solving the issue with non-existent IDs:**

Once you get an ID, you want to check if it exists or not, you just have to execute a SELECT and see if it returned any records, using something like `mysqli_num_rows` or its OO counterpart.
Complete codde snippet would be something like:

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $the_id = $_GET['id']; // I'd personally use filter_input here
    } else {
        // redirect to google if $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is not set
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ?? 'http://google.com');
        exit;
    }

    // assuming you already have the $connection object available here
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $the_id); // note that this is the safe way to pass user input to a SQL query to avoid SQL injection
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result(); // required to use "num_rows" below
    if ($stmt->num_rows === 0) {
        // no user record was found with the given ID
        // redirect to google if $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is not set
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ?? 'http://google.com');
        exit;
    }

    // at this point you're sure that a user with id $the_id exists, so you can continue your code flow as expected :-)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. Unless I've misunderstood your answer? I've used your code in the 'else' part of the initial code block in my question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Hi @Anna_p, it should work, I've updated my response to include the code in it.

Comment: no this doesn't work either. It just has the same problem. If someone types an id value into the url parameter that doesn't exist the table just disappears. It doesn't redirect.

Comment: right! this just solves the issue with the lack of `$_GET['id']`, I'll amend my reply to include checking the id existence.

Comment: This still doesn't work. I seem to be going backwards. Also, why would I need to use a prepared statement when reading data from a database when 'htmlspecialchars()' converts all data to a string that is safe to output? Also I don't need the ID to be an integer, all url parameters are strings? Reading about HTTP_REFERER it seems I shouldn't use it like this for security reasons, but instead use a path to the file I want to show on redirect. I feel what should be relatively simple problem is making we want to bang my head against the wall.

Comment: ...I do appreciate you trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

And what says that "referrer" exists?  And would it necessarily still point to your page?

- The hacker copied the URL, modified it, then pasted it into a new window.  No page to "go back to".
- The hacker somehow gets "referrer" to go to his page.

You need to assume that anything wrong could mean that everything is wrong.  The hacker does not deserve to be sent anywhere other than a 404-like page.

Answer (score -1):

!st method in php
In PHP you can make use of the `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` variable in the `header()` statement like so .

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] );
exit;
```

good idea to follow a header() statement with an exit or code execution will continue through the rest of the script as normal.

2nd method javscript

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
function goBack() {
window.history.back();
}
```

i hope you get the answer of your question .